# insert array of data in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

i m using loopback and don't know how to insert array of data using sing api for eg  i have data like

```
 view: [ true, false, false ],
 edit: [ false, true, false ],
 update: [ false, false, true ],
 product: [ 1, 2, 3]
```

now i want to insert data like this in table

```
  product | view | edit |update 
----------------------------------
     1    |true  |false |false 
     2    |false |false |true  
     3    |false |false |true
```

i know i can use for loop but don't know where to use i.e whether this is possible in remote hook method or remote method can can one suggest me idea how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-create

> PersistedModel.create([data], callback) Create new instance of Model,
>   and save to database.
>
> Arguments Name    Type    Description [data]  Object or Array.
>   Optional data argument. **Can be either a single model instance or an
>   array of instances**.

Create can take an array of instances.  `POST` with an array in the request body and it will insert them all.

EDIT 
In your case I think you have to create a remote method.  Model specific validation will fire after `before save`, but the default POST method validation will not allow you to submit an array of arrays.  Here's some example code, replace `assembled` with however you create your array of objects from your array of arrays

```
  MyModel.assembleAndInsert = async (data, cb) => {
    // Assemble the data
    let assembled = [{name: 'iecream'}];
    debugger;
    let result = await MyModel.create(assembled);
    cb(null, result);
  };

  MyModel.remoteMethod('assembleAndInsert', {
    http: {
      path: '/assembleAndInsert',
      verb: 'post',
      status: 200,
      errorStatus: 400,
    },
    accepts: [{ arg: 'data', type: 'array', http: { source: 'body' } }],
    returns: {
      arg: 'created',
      type: 'Array',
    },
  });
```

Comment: where should I use PersistedModel.create([data], callback)  should I create remote method or I can use remote before becuase insertion is performing in same model

Comment: I didn't read your question properly, edited answer should answer better

Comment: thanks for you help one last  will this return response along with  some database for eg:- in angular if you do
 console.log in success like console.log(response.data) will it contain any data

Comment: on success it returns the array of created models like a regular create statement `"created": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "iecream"
    }
  ]`